# Right Click Contextmenu incorrectly displaying after returning false on menu

Tags: php, jquery, contextmenu, right-click

first time poster but use this site for examples all the time. My small problem is this (and I've researched it, but can't find a solution to my problem)...

I have a text list of 50+ names, and one item for each day, (so a matrix of 50+ x 7) where I want to be able to right click on daily text (a div per day), and display a menu relating specifically to that item per day. This would be no big deal, however, because I need to identify every item individually and use the DivID by JS to call another function, this becomes a big deal. I looked at other jquery menu options, but couldn't figure out how to dynamically retrieve the name correctly.

The problem I have is not creating the menu and capturing the item ID, but it's stopping the ContextMenu from appearing after the right click has been made.

I want the page to have the right click menu elsewhere, but not on these DIV elements, the just menu I'm creating.

The following code has been simplified...

This is the JS I'm using:

```
function go(e,idname) 
    {
     var rightclick;
     e = e || window.event;
     if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
     else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);       
     var a = idname.id;
     a = (a.substring(11));  

     ShowContent('ToggleValueFloat');   // Display the DIV      

     $(document).ready(function() 
         {
          $('#ToggleValueFloat').html('MY MENU TEXT' + <a href="Javascript:ToggleDay(' + a + ');">EXAMPLE</a>);         
          return false;
         }); 

    return false; 
    }


function ShowContent(d) {
    if(d.length < 1) { return; }
    var dd = document.getElementById(d);
    AssignPosition(dd);
    dd.style.display = "block";
}
```

This is the PHP I'm using for the example:

```
echo  '<a id="togglePopup' . (int)$arrayEId[$allEntries] . '" onmousedown="go(event,this); return false;">example</a>';
```

This is the DIV I'm using to show.

```
<div id="ToggleValueFloat" style="display:none;  position:absolute;  border-style: solid;  background-color: white;  padding: 5px;"></div>
```

I'm trying to get it to return false every time so the Context menu won't display, but it doesn't work. I can disable right click altogether on the page, but this will prove more unproductive than ever.

Any thoughts/help would be great! I'm open to options. Thanks, Steve

Comment: Your code is very hard to read without proper indentation.

Comment: Sorry, I struggled getting it in with the code tags here on SOF.

Comment: You just indent every line four spaces and it will then preserve your other indentation and display it as code.  The `{}` tool in the editor will indent a block four spaces to show it as code.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this is a problem:

```
 if (!e) var e = window.event;
```

which, since all variable declarations are hoisted is the same as this:

```
 var e;
 if (!e) e = window.event;
```

You have an argument named `e` and now you're creating a local variable of the same name which will override it.  You should replace that line with this to just reassign the argument `e` if it's undefined:

```
e = e || window.event;
```

As to your targeting problem why don't you just look at the object in the event that the mouse is targeted at and figure out (before you display the menu) if the targeted object is one that you want to show the menu on or not and then only call the code that shows the menu if the click comes on a desired target.

Comment: Thanks for the quick hint. I've amended my code for that. :) But, with my menu it's being created fine, but the usual right click browser menu is displaying on top of the menu I make, which it shouldn't, as I've told it to "return false"...? The browser menu shouldn't be displaying at all.

Comment: Ahhh, you didn't say your problem was with the standard browser right-click menu (or I didn't understand that).  Some browsers do not allow you to control the right-click menu any more and some have a preference setting to determine whether a web page is allowed to defeat the right-click menu or not.  By default, I think that the latest versions of both Chrome and Firefox don't let a web page defeat the standard right-click menu.  Even Google maps has this problem.

Comment: Hmmm. The strange thing is I can put in this.....
"alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick);".....just after the mouse detection from  ..... 
  "http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html" .....
and I don't get the browser menu... weird. I'm using the lastest FF.

Comment: [This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=1395) shows you where you can control a web page's ability to block/replace the right-click menu in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your help in this. I realised there must have been another way to do this after you mentioned the whole browser right click control, so I found this and modified it to work with what I needed in the end.  http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/gW3fA/